# Android - AsyncTask, SQLite and Context

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using AsyncTask to download and parse data in a separate thread and I need to pass in the values returned by loadXml into the database.

The problem is that I can't instantiate the database because it requires a context and my DownloadXmlTask is in a separate class to the activity class where it is instantiated.

How do I use pass the values into the database if I can't instantiate the database class?

Code Sample:

```
public class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

public static final String TAG = "VotingApp";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        // Get the parsed list of Candidate objects
        ArrayList<Candidate> candidatesList = loadXml(urls[0]);
        CandidatesDatabaseHelper db = new CandidatesDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); <---- ERROR (I know I can't use getApplicationContext() here)

        // Insert the candidates into the database
        for(Candidate c : candidatesList){
                      //NOT FINISHED
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error " + e);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error " + e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "NOT WORKING");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve that problem by making AsyncTask an inner class, but if you just do it the way you are currently doing it then technically you could do `AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void>`:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... urls) {
    Context context = (Context)urls[0]; //should always be true by your own rules
    /*then you can also loop the urls for the rest of the Strings to cast
    **if there are going to be more. Or not. Your choice*/
//.....
```

instead of `String`. When calling `.execute(this, someString)`, send it the Context first and the String second. Then you just cast each of them into their appropriate variables. Try that and let me know if it works. Can't test it out right now unfortunately so you're going to have to test it.

Comment: I thought you were always supposed to ensure that you separate backend work from the activity classes in Android?

Comment: Well it depends. Nothing wrong with having an inner class. It affords you some perks. BUT, if you plan on reusing it in other Activities, then you are doing it perfectly fine. Also, readability is important at times. So its preference. But try what I posted above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: So I changed my code to the following:                                                                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  new DownloadXmlTask().execute(getApplicationContext(), URL);
 }

Comment: Now change `DownloadXmlTask` as well to make it work with your code. Use what little code a put to help you out. Do a test to make sure you get the database helper.

Comment: I get an error when I try to download: protected Void doInBackground(Object... urls) {
  try {
   // Get the parsed list of Candidate objects
   Context context = (Context) urls[0];
   ArrayList<Candidate> candidatesList = loadXml((String) urls[0]);
   CandidatesDatabaseHelper db = new CandidatesDatabaseHelper(context);
   
   Log.d(TAG, "Size" + candidatesList.size());

Comment: Whats the error? But you're doing `loadXml((String) urls[0]);`, you should be doing `loadXml((String) urls[1]);`

Comment: why should I use urls[1] instaed of urls[0]?

Comment: Because `urls` is an array. When you say `new DownloadXmlTask().execute(getApplicationContext(), URL);` the parameters you send are put into an array. So with your rule of index 0 being Context, the rest will be Strings.